# How can i allow a user to edit their own account details?

Tags: php, codeigniter

how would i allow a user to edit their own account details. When they login, a session is created with their username. How do i query the database where i match the session to a user in the database? Im confused as to where to do it, controller, or model? Here is my code. Its not much because i really don't know where to start with this:

Controller:

```
public function myaccount()
 {
     if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
{

$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
$this->myaccount_model->get_details($data);
$this->load->model('myaccount_model');
$this->load->view('head');
$this->load->view('myaccount', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');

}
else
{
 redirect('login', 'refresh');
}
 }
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Myaccount_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_details()
{
$query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
return $query->row_array();

}
}
```

I am getting the error message :Undefined property: Navigate::$myaccount_model.

I know its something to do with how I'm passing the users id from the controller to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the model before using its functions

```
$this->myaccount_model->get_details($data);
$this->load->model('myaccount_model');
```

to

```
$this->load->model('myaccount_model');
$this->myaccount_model->get_details($session_data['id']);
```

edit:

If you want to get details from a specific id (session id), 
add a parameter in your `get_details($id)` function located in your model.

for example:

```
public function get_details($id){
   $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1);
   return $query->row_array();
}
```

Then call it in your controller like this:

`$result = $this->myaccount_model->get_details($session_data['id']);`

Now pass this `$result` to your view.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have var dumped the $id in the view and it is recognising it. However, i need to pass the $data (userid so its $id) to the model so that i can query the database? This is confusing

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look. Although I'm not exacly sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're setting a user ID in the session so you could use

```
$id = $this->session->get_userdata('id');
return $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
```

Instead of username, you passed the userid

```
$data['userid'] = $session_data['userid'];
```